# BSOD after PC has been running for a while

Tags: power-supply, bsod

I'm having a problem where my computer is getting a blue screen. I have noticed that the BSOD happens after the PC has been running for about 2 days.  The BSOD's seem to be an error with atikmpag.sys with an error code of 0x00000116. The problem started about a month ago.It has happened all five times that I left my computer on that long in the past month.

Because my computer is a pre-built one from Dell, and I had upgraded the graphics card (at least a year ago) to a more demanding one, I replaced the stock 360W power supply that came with it. I replaced it with a more powerful, 680W one, because it seemed like the problem could be related to a lack of power supply wattage, but it didn't affect the problem at all. I have also run Memtest86+, and no errors were found.

Here are the minidump files for the five BSOD's that I have experienced:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3488338/bsoddumps.zip

System info:

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- Dell Studio XPS 435MT
- Radeon HD 5670 (Version 12.4 of the Catalyst driver)
- Intel Core i7 920 2.67 GHz
- 6GB of RAM

Comment: What version of Windows? What version of the graphics driver did you install? What graphics card did you add to it (unless you mean the Radeon HD 5670)

Comment: @Luke I updated the post with this information. The 5670 was the card that I added.

Comment: Has this problem only been occurring since you upgraded the video or was it happening prior to this?

Comment: @jmreicha I updated the video a long time ago, at least a year ago. This problem only started happening a month ago.

Comment: Run Memtest86 for a while.  Betting bad RAM.

Comment: @ultrasawblade Thanks, I'll try that, but I still would appreciate other opinions.

Comment: So it could potentially be a bad driver?  In addition to testing RAM I would also suggest testing the Hard drive for bad sectors.

Comment: U can look into the Windows Event Viewer to possibly find out what is happenning.

Comment: I have run Memtest86+ and no errors were found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see.

[This thread at Overclock.net](http://www.overclock.net/t/1237672/display-driver-stopped-responding-atikmpag-sys-0x00000116-bsod-new-his-7950) was started by someone using an ATI card, getting that same BSOD (error and file).  People suggested multiple different theories, and one of them pointed to a [driver related issue and solution](http://www.overclock.net/t/1234179/atikmdag-sys-bsod-12-2-drivers/20#post_16830070) that worked for some people (apparently this isn't uncommon).  In the first thread however, it turned out to be a faulty card that the owner got replaced for free by the manufacturer.

So.  here is what I would do.  First, follow these instructions from that second link I gave you...

> Try and do it in this order: [[Fixes] Catalyst Drivers Error & OC & Eyefinity & General Issues](http://www.overclock.net/t/1226892/fixes-catalyst-drivers-error-oc-eyefinity-general-issues)
>
> 1. Uninstall Afterburner and Catalyst from manager.
> 2. Clean it with [Atiman Uninstaller v.6.3.1](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=7777bc3c17029328d03146e0ed767841&loc=http://www.overclock.net/t/1196856/official-amd-radeon-hd-7950-7970-owners-club&v=1&libid=1339811443996&ref=http://www.overclock.net/t/1237672/display-driver-stopped-responding-atikmpag-sys-0x00000116-bsod-new-his-7950&title=atikmdag.sys%20bsod%2012.2%20drivers&txt=Atiman%20Uninstaller%20v.6.3.1&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13398117648621&out=http://www.mediafire.com/?sja6d1z3t2ld6as) (turn off UAC to install this).
> 3. Install 1/25/2012 http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/previous/12/Pages/radeon.aspx?os=Windows%20Vista%20-%2064-Bit%20Edition&rev=12.1
> 4. Install [MSI Afterburner 2.2.0 Beta 14](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=7777bc3c17029328d03146e0ed767841&loc=http://www.overclock.net/t/1234179/atikmdag-sys-bsod-12-2-drivers/20#post_16830070&v=1&libid=1339811443996&out=http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=msi%2520afterburner%25202.2.0%2520beta%252014%2520download&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.guru3d.com%252Fnews%252Fmsi-afterburner-220-beta-14-download%252F&ei=6sZDT_PLIYXorQfw943pBw&usg=AFQjCNGk2nnf3j3Ze6UDzTgpS1eR5Pw3nA&ref=http://www.overclock.net/t/1237672/display-driver-stopped-responding-atikmpag-sys-0x00000116-bsod-new-his-7950&title=atikmdag.sys%20bsod%2012.2%20drivers&txt=MSI%20Afterburner%202.2.0%20Beta%2014%20Download&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13398118430445) Download
> 5. Enable "unoffcial overclocking" HOW TO: [Enable UNOFFICIAL overclocking mode in MSI AfterBurner](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=7777bc3c17029328d03146e0ed767841&loc=http://www.overclock.net/t/1215131/no-voltage-control-on-6970-in-afterburner-need-a-fresh-set-of-eyes-and-hopefully-smarter-than-me#post_16458810&v=1&libid=1339811443996&ref=http://www.overclock.net/t/1237672/display-driver-stopped-responding-atikmpag-sys-0x00000116-bsod-new-his-7950&title=atikmdag.sys%20bsod%2012.2%20drivers&txt=HOW%20TO:%20Enable%20UNOFFICIAL%20overclocking%20mode%20in%20MSI%20AfterBurner&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13398118641057&out=http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=7777bc3c17029328d03146e0ed767841&loc=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.overclock.net%252Ft%252F1201093%252Freference-6950-oc-help%2523post_16209495&v=1&libid=1326763395927&out=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Furl%253Fsa%253Dt%2526rct%253Dj%2526q%253Dhow%252520to%252520enable%252520unofficial%252520afterburner%2526source%253Dweb%2526cd%253D1%2526ved%253D0CB8QFjAA%2526url%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fforums.guru3d.com%25252Fshowthread.php%25253Ft%25253D338906%2526ei%253DKc4UT7y2E47KrAek9KjtAQ%2526usg%253DAFQjCNE9w3OJUvktjyD3DvF1jLiC2PjXUg&ref=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.overclock.net%252Fusers%252Fsubscriptions%252Findex%252Fview%252Factivity&title=reference%25206950%2520OC%2520help&txt=%253CEM%253EHOW%2520TO%253A%2520Enable%2520UNOFFICIAL%253C%252FEM%253E%2520overclocking%2520mode%2520in%2520MSI%2520%253CEM%253EAfterBurner%253C%252FEM%253E&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13267637527212)
> 6. Afterburner settings > enable all voltage controls.
>
> Note: Exit Afterburner prior to editing .cfg file and ULPS.
>
> Crossfire User- Do the following between steps 4 and 5:
>
> Disable ULPS:
>
> - Go to regedit (start > search programs and files > "regedit").
> - In drop down menu: find file > type "enableulps".
> - For ALL instances (keep pressing F3) change the "1" value to a "0".
> - Reboot PC.
>
> Edit:
>
> Use latest Afternurner 2.2.0 Beta 15

.. and again, this seemed to work for some of the people with the same error code and system file popping up on a BSOD.  If that doesn't work, look into getting the card replaced under warranty (if you can).

Comment: Thanks for finding this. I searched for a long time but I didn't find that thread. Step 3 is a link to a driver for a video card that isn't mine. Should I install it anyway or is there an equivalent one for my 5670?

Comment: @user1389999 good point.  Dig around the AMD site for an equivalent, and I will do the same when I am not on my phone

Comment: @user1389999 Ok.  Released at the same time as the RC11 set (january of 2012) was version 12.1 for the 5xxx series.  I've edited the answer with a different link... one to version 12.1 drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I followed these instructions, and my computer has now been on for three days and it hasn't BSOD'd since then. I think it fixed my problem.

Comment: @bdr9 I'll keep my fingers crossed for you